# Laminas - Unable to render template "xxxxxxx" resolver could not resolve to a file

Tags: php, zend-framework2, port, laminas

This project has been ported over manually from Zend Frame work 2 to Laminas. The issue here is that the module.config.php has been set up in the same way as other modules that are working. However I am encountering this error. I have checked the usually culprits such as files spelling or missing, no other modules are using the same route name. Is there another part of Laminas that would affect the view manager?

The modul.config.php setup is below.

'''
namespace ProjectTaskDocument;

```
            use Laminas\Router\Http\Segment;
            
            return [
                'router' => [
                    'routes' => [
                        'project-task-document' => [
                            'type' => Segment::class,
                            'options' => [
                                'route' => '/task-document[/:action][/:id]',
                                'constraints' => [
                                    'action' => 'index|add|download|view-all|delete'
                                ],
                                'defaults' => [
                                    'controller' => Controller\ProjectTaskDocumentController::class,
                                    'action' => 'index'
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'view_manager' => [
                    'template_path_stack' => [
                        'ProjectTaskDocument' => __DIR__ . '/../view'
                    ],
                ]
            ];
```

'''

[The module folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE2RM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised my mistake, during my port process another module was using the same Key identifier for the view_manager->template_path_stack. I feel pretty damn dumb for missing this.